# When reading an SD card in SPI Mode, how do I distinguish a data token from an error token?

Tags: spi

For SPI read, send CMD27, get back command response followed by either data token and data or error token.

```
Data token is  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
Error token is 0 0 0 X X X X X
```

The problem is as far as I can tell, idle reads as a stream of 1 bits so if I lay the mask like this on the error token I get a valid data token:

```
                    start error token here
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 X X X X X X 1 1 1 1
      start data token here
```

If the first data byte read starts with two zero bits (highly probable), this is ambiguous with error token. Looking for end of stream doesn't work as this yields infinite 1 bits. (I anticipate long streams of 1 bits in legitimate reads).

It gets worse considering CMD28 reading across a bad sector (I need long range CMD28 to make my performance requirements). Looking for end of stream swallows the next data start packet.

I do in fact have code (about 70 lines) that can successfully initialize the SD card over this interface and read its configuration registers. I can easily send the read command just fine. But I don't know how to write the code to tell if the response back is success for error.

(Sorry, no code to show. You really wanna see nothing but an ASM loop pulling bits out of a pin?)

Comment: what chip are you using? is there no spi module in it such that you have to use asm to poll bit stream?

Comment: The chip does not have SPI hardware.

Comment: and you description is very poor. is your SPI `serial peripheral interface`? there are several modes spi can run in. which are you referring to? did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus for an example implementation?

Comment: This is four-wire SPI with the SD card directly wired to the other end (OK so there's a fifth wire providing a hardware card detect). I have no idea what SPI modes even are. I have a bunch of wave diagrams for how an SD card is supposed to respond to different signals. I believe it being *not* byte aligned due to a 76 clocks appearing in the initialization phase documentation before sending the first command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After issuing the read block command (CMD17) or read multiple block (CMD18) command, the card will output all 1s until it returns R1 (please correct me if I am wrong).

After returning R1 the card will signal all 1s (reading the spec I get the impression that BUSY is only allowed after a data transfer, unless the response type for that command is R1b in table 7-3).

The first byte which is not all 1s after R1 will be either the data token (`0xFE`) or it will be the error token (`0x0X` where X is from 1 to F).